# $(r^2-s^2)^2-(5\cdot\min\{r,s\})=2015$. Find all positive integer solution of this equation.

Tags: functional-equations

I know the $\min\{x,y\}$ means the minimum value of $x$ and $y$. and it can be expressed as, $\min\{x,y\}= \frac12\left( x+y-\sqrt{(x-y)^2}\right)$

Comment: Sorry but we are not able to understand your question. Please consider using Math jax, here's the tutorial! http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, assume $r>s$.
There is the solution $(7,2)$ when $r^2-s^2=45$
Otherwise, 
$$r^2-s^2\geq50\\
5s\geq485\\
s\geq97\\
r\geq98\\
(r^2-s^2)^2-5s\geq(2r-1)^2-5r=4r^2-9r+1>3r^2>2015
$$